# Skip first line File.ReadAllText for SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, csv

I have been working on this code to create a CSV Import that can be done through a webapp now what I am running into is the first row of the CSV file has headers and when I do the import I was that first line to not be in the SqlBulkCopy. Here is the code.

```
public partial class CS : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Upload and save the file
        string csvPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(csvPath);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[15] { new DataColumn("ORGANIZATION_ID", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("INVENTORY_ITEM_ID", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("ITEM_CODE", typeof(char)),
            new DataColumn("SUBINVENTORY_CODE", typeof(char)),
            new DataColumn("LOCATOR_ID", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("LOCATOR_CODE", typeof(char)),
            new DataColumn("QTY", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("FLOWRACK", typeof(char)),
            new DataColumn("LOCATOR_POSITION", typeof(char)),
            new DataColumn("LOCATOR_BIN_LEVEL", typeof(char)),
            new DataColumn("PICKING_ORDER", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("ITEM_BOX_QUANTITY", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("AVAILABLE_BOX_QTY", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("AVAILABLE_MOD_QTY", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("CreateTime", typeof(DateTime)) });
        string csvData = File.ReadAllText(csvPath);
        foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row) )
            {
                dt.Rows.Add();
                int i = 0;
                    foreach (string cell in row.Split(','))
                {
                        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;
                        i++;

                }
            }   
        }

        string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
        {
            using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
            {
                //Set the database table name
                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Inventory";
                con.Open();
                sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the error I get is

> Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Source Error:

> Line 46:                                             foreach (string cell in row.Split(','))
>   Line 47:                                         {
>   Line 48:                                                 dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;
>   Line 49:                                                 i++;
>   Line 50:

I am also using sql server 2008
Can someone help me out?

Comment: I am still having a problem now the error i get is Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2010 Compiler version 4.0.30319.1 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. c:\inetpub\wwwroot\CSV_insert\CS.aspx.cs(60,66): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'char.GetNumericValue(char)' has some invalid arguments c:\inetpub\wwwroot\CSV_insert\CS.aspx.cs(60,87): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char' any one have any ideas?

Comment: Where I have typeof char I think I actually might need typeof string as an example item_code would be dmsmh.en.cd. So how would I modify the code to work in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `File.ReadAllLines()` instead for `File.ReadAllText(csvPath)`. Which helps you to skip the Split operation as well as the First line; See the code below:

```
List<string> csvDataList = File.ReadAllLines(csvPath).Skip(1).ToList();
```

Now the `csvDataList` is a list of rows except the first row, you can iterate through those rows and do the same functions:

Iteration Example:

```
 foreach (string Csv in csvDataList)
 {
     DataRow dRow = dt.NewRow();
     int i = 0;
     foreach (string cell in Csv.Split(','))
     {
           if (dRow[i].GetType() == typeof(int))
           {
               int cellValue = 0;
               if (Int32.TryParse(cell, out cellValue))
               {
                  dRow[i++] = cellValue;
               }
            }
            else if (dRow[i].GetType() == typeof(char) && cell.Length == 1)
            {
                dRow[i++] = cell[0];
            }
            else // Which means that the cell is of type int
                dRow[i++] = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(cell[0]);
     }
     dt.Rows.Add(dRow);
 }
```

Comment: When I do this I get: **Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Split' and no extension method 'Split' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Comment: I have updated the code with sample iteration, Please go through that

Comment: Okay we are getting somewhere! Now I have:
`Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Source Error: 


Line 45:                                 foreach (string cell in Csv.Split(','))
Line 46:                                 {
Line 47:                                     dRow[0] = cell;
Line 48:                                 }
Line 49:                                 dt.Rows.Add(dRow);`
Error on Line: 47

Comment: The `cell` will always be a string and most of the columns in the table(`dt`) are integer type, you cannot assign a string to an integer, you need to convert them as integer

Comment: I don't understand why it would tell me **ArgumentException: Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <"152"> in ORGANIZATION_ID Column.  Expected type is Int32.** is 152 is int, right?

Comment: `152` is int but it is `"152"`, I have few more updates to the answer please check

Comment: @TommyGraffam: Have you checked? is that working now?

Comment: So I am getting the same ArgumentException with the updated code, I cant quite figure out what needs to be changed to turn it from Char to Int32.

Comment: @TommyGraffam :  use `(int)Char.GetNumericValue('8');` to get  int equivalent of char

Comment: Where would I put (int)Char.GetNumericValue('8');?

Comment: where you are getting the exception there you use, use the char instead for `'8'`

Comment: I am still not getting where this should go. Can you edit it into the above code you created?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114809/discussion-between-tommy-graffam-and-un-lucky).

Comment: Alright now with that update I get **Compiler Error Message: CS1502:** The best overloaded method match for 'char.GetNumericValue(char)' has some invalid arguments                                                                          **Line 60:                   dRow[i++] = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(cell);**

Comment: I wanted to put what I am currently gettiing an error on and maybe you could help me **


Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2010 Compiler version 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

c:\inetpub\wwwroot\CSV_insert\CS.aspx.cs(60,66): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'char.GetNumericValue(char)' has some invalid arguments
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\CSV_insert\CS.aspx.cs(60,87): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'**

Comment: And this error comes up before I even have a chance to upload the csv file which is different from the other errors.

Comment: I am still having trouble getting this to work, canyou help me out?